# Value of Jquery object index

Tags: jquery

I have got this code snippet:

```
    var $ispan = $(window.test.document.getElementsByTagName("span"));
    for (var i=5; i<$ispan.size(); i++) {
        $('.content').append('<br>' + $ispan[i].text());
    };
```

So $ispan contains a collection of spans. I am trying to append a specific selection of those spans to my body. The code is failing at

```
$ispan[i].text()
```

Why doesn't this work and how should it be done?

Comment: Start by replacing `$(window.test.document.getElementsByTagName("span"));` by `$('span')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets return a specific DOM-node from the jQuery object/collection, rather than a jQuery object; which fails because the native DOM node has no `text()` method. So, instead, you should use:

```
$('.content').append('<br>' + $ispan.eq(i).text());
```

[Proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v2AY7/1/)

Note, in the linked 'proof-of-concept,' that I amended the approach to append the elements, switching it to:

```
$ispan.eq(i).text('span ' + (i+1)).appendTo('.content').before('<br />');
```

This is because, with the approach written above (which you say works, in the comments) the output was lots of `[Object object]` in the `.content` element.

The above alternative finds the relevant element in the jQuery object, sets its text, appends it to the `.content` element then inserts a `<br />` *before* the appended element.

Also, your original selector should be adequately replaced by `$('span')`, rather than an over-complicated jQuery-wrapped native DOM selector.

You say, in comments elsewhere, that you need to work on a '[specific set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518210/value-of-jquery-object-index/15518236#comment21978315_15518254)' of `span` elements, which I'm assuming is why you use the `for() {...}`, you could instead use `:gt()`:

```
var $ispan = $("span:gt(4)");
$ispan.text(function (i) {
    return 'span ' + (i + 6);
}).appendTo('.content').before('<br />');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v2AY7/3/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: This is working correctly, thank you, will mark for answer in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var $ispan = $('span');
$ispan.each(function(index) {
    if(index > 3)
       $('.content').append('<br>' + $(this).text());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You compiled javascript with jQuery. This is not necessary. Use only javascript or jQuery. It is most recommended.
Use eq() to find elements, and start the for() with 0.

Try it:

```
var ispan = $("span");
    for (var i = 0; i < ispan.length; i++) {
        $('.content').append('<br>' + ispan.eq(i).text());
    };
```